# Derivation of gaussian graphical model in undirected graphical models

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, graphical-model

I tried to figure out the mathematical calculation related to  gaussian graphical model given in the book "Elements of Statistical Learning". But I am not able to conclude

(1) How they calculated conditional mean and variance matrix.

(2) And the calculation related to $\theta$ that they have used in calculation is not clear.

This is what given in the book:
[image]

I am a beginner in ML. So these calculations is not clear to me. Please help me!

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions at once...

Comment: Sir,but  all the questions are related to same concept, gaussian graphical  model. Anyway I will take care of this in future.

Comment: While they are related to the same concept, they are all valid stand-alone questions. I'm just trying to give you a hint how to ask a well-received question on this site, since asking a multiple questions at once might be a reason for closing the question.

Comment: Ok Sir, I have edited the question now. Is it fine now?

Comment: Great! I hope you will get the answers you are looking for. Of course, feel free to post the removed parts of the question in a separate thread(s).